# How to delete .yaml elements like maps or arrays efficiently in Vim?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode

I often need to edit huge .yaml files, where I need to delete entire maps or arrays.

My current approach is to go into visual (line-wise) mode (`Shift + V`) and mark the lines manually, but that feels cumbersome compared to editing HTML tags in Vim (e.g. `dit`)

How can I efficiently delete .yaml elements in Vim?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another great use of [indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object): I believe `dii` or one of the other maps would do it here.

Comment: Thanks, I assume there is no Vim native way then, which I would have anticipated, since I often need such functionality on remote systems. Can you describe how to install `indent-object` as a Vim package? I don't use `vim-plug` and have no intention to install it.

Comment: As a package, you just put the source (or submodule or whatever you want) in `~/.vim/pack/<some arbitrary name>/start/indent-object` @Shuzheng

Comment: Thanks. By "submodule" you mean `git` submodule?

Comment: Yes; I use git to track files like this so I use submodules to manage packages.

Comment: `indent-object` seems to work very well with .yaml maps, but it fails for arrays, i.e. it's not possible to remove a single array element etc., since indentation for arrays is the same as for the surrounding map